# Javascript function call in HTML - want it in jQuery only

Tags: jquery

I have a markup like this:

```
<body onLoad="func();" onResize="func();" id="myId">
```

I was wondering how can I trigger this just through jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', func);
    func();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "body" ).on( "load resize", func );
$( "body" ).trigger( "resize" );
```

Comment: This calls the function 2 times, first on _load_ event and again on triggering the _resize_.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').bind('load resize', func);
```